# How to replace columns name in pandas dataframe with a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very wide dataframe with over 1000 columns with each column name being a number1-1000 in sequential order (so the 2nd column is 2, third column is 3 etc).  I have a list of column names, that are positional, meaning if I can take my column list in the order I have it, and just replace entire index row of the dataframe with it, I'd have exactly what I need.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df.columns = pd.Index(list_of_names)` doesn't work, you can use:

```
df = df.rename(dict(zip(df.columns, list_of_names)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3))
df.columns = ['Col A', 'Col B', 'Col C']
print(df)
```

Result:

```
      Col A     Col B     Col C
0  0.497856  0.373009  0.719566
1  0.126019  0.823805  0.570156
2  0.588741  0.405167  0.557865
```

Alternative solution:

```
df.rename(columns={0: 'Col A', 1: 'Col B', 2: 'Col C'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I'm using python 3.5 so that df.columns = [] doesn't work, and I know I can df.rename, but I have over 1000 columns...

Comment: And `df.columns = pd.Index(list_of_names)` works?

Comment: It should work, regardless of Python version. When you say *it doesn't work* you should always specify the error.